# Does Xamarin Support project.json for NuGet?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Does Xamarin support using a project.json file instead of a package.config file for NuGet? I can't find a definitive answer online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now no. but...

Have you seen this [post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59641/nuget-v3-with-project-json) on the Xamarin forums:

> I was just looking to see what the plans are for supporting NuGet v3 and project.json in XS?
>
> There are plans to add support for NuGet v3 at some point. The main problem is that it is not as straightforward as just updating the Xamarin Studio client to support NuGet v3. We need to add support into the build tools for iOS and Android. With Microsoft releasing the NuGet build tasks we are another step closer though.
> Yes there is an open bug on Bugzilla for NuGet 3 support.

I would follow this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34694) for updates.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been added.  See this blog post from Miguel de Icaza about it.
I'm quoting the relevant parts here for posterity's sake.

[Major Updates: iOS 10, Android Nougat, and Other Tasty Bits](https://blog.xamarin.com/major-updates-ios-10-android-nougat-and-other-tasty-bits/)

> NuGet 3 Support
>   In this release, we’ve also added support for NuGet 3 and the new package file format, project.json, and support for transitive restore of packages and dependencies. Any package that now targets NuGet 3 specifically can be installed and will show up in the NuGet feed when searching for packages.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on! ;)

If you mean parts of your solution, it is a *yes*. If you create a new Xamarin solution the UWP project unsurprisingly already contains a `project.json` file. But of course this is not really Xamarin.

On the other hand I have not find any possibilities to switch an Android- or iOS-project to project.json.

If you read on [nuget.org](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/ProjectJson-Intro) there is only support for UWP, PCL and ASP.NET Core yet.

So if you ask for a PCL - this is possible. You can create a new project or you can [switch](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/08/19/using-project-json-for-other-project-types/) (I did not try it) your project to using this file.

Comment: You are right that using a project.json file is technically supported for PCL projects. But that applies only to using PCL projects in Visual Studio. It's not supported by Xamarin yet (because it doesn't support Nuget 3 at the moment). You might be using Xamarin for your PCL projects, so IMO it doesn't even fully support PCL.